# How To Use "textBox1_TextChanged" Under "textBox1_KeyDown" Function?

Tags: c#, keyboard-events, keydown, textchanged

I am using two functions on a textBox1 that are `textBox1_TextChanged` and  `textBox1_KeyDown` as my desired code is to run after hitting some keys and on text change and working fine as below.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextChanged();
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    KeysPressed(sender, e);
}
```

But ٰI want to run my both function under `textBox1_KeyDown()` only using the below concept.

```
private string currentText = "";
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{    
    if (currentText != textBox1.Text)
    {
        TextChanged();
    }
    currentText = textBox1.Text;
    KeysPressed(sender, e);
}
```

My problem is that my `TextChanged();` in upper code runs after adding two characters. I want it to run on every character and on add/delete/edit/paste/replace in `textBox1` so any ideas to make it work on first hit on the `textBox1_KeyDown()` function?

### Explained:

I understand my problem as when I use `textBox1_KeyDown()` event then it run the inner code `TextChanged();` first then it work for its own work like I press a character then it will run `TextChanged();` then will type that character in the `textBox1` so that's why my `TextChanged();` is not able to detect any changed in text. So how to fix this...???

Comment: @Sam I am; Yes, I need to run `TextChanged();` to run on every character add/delete/edit/paste/replace in `textBox1`.

Comment: Do you have a `Form.KeyPreview` set? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx

Comment: @Jacobr365 No, This is it what I am using totally...

Comment: You need to append the character that the user typed with the existing content of the text box in your if statement. Wait, there is a catch, the keydown event will fire for *any* key, so if you press a down arrow or other control keys, then this appending logic will throw exception...Now, you need to decide whatever you are trying to achieve can be achieved in some other way instead of relaying on KeyDown event.

Comment: @Thangadurai My `KeysPressed(sender, e);` function contain some work done on arrows keys, enter key, escape key etc. Can you explain little more with coding ideas...???

Comment: @Sam I am, @Jacobr365; See my updated question...

Answer (score 0):

From your question i assumed that your problem that at first hit for `textBox1_KeyDown` `TextChanged();` is not called. Only at second hit it will be called successfully. If my understanding is right then i think the problem is with your if statement as at startup both textBox1 text and currentText will be equals as both are empty string.

Comment: You could modify your statement to be like this 
'if (currentText != textBox1.Text || currentText == "")
    {
        TextChanged();
    }'

Comment: Thanks for your Tip... :)